# validating controls in tabs winforms

Tags: c#, validation, .net-4.0

Im implementing application which has main window and in this second window which has a lot of tabs in tabcontrol.

On each tab I have a lot of control which values may be edited by user, some of them has to be filled, some need to has values between x and y and so on.

Main windows has got save button. Point is that if in any tab control isnt validated then saving shouldnt be possible and appropriate tab should be opened and validation shown. Could you please tell me any advice of how to create such mechanism ? Maybe any generic methods ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Try this link

[WinForms TabControl validation: Switch to a tab where validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272385/winforms-tabcontrol-validation-switch-to-a-tab-where-validation-failed)

```
Dictionary<TabPage, HashSet<Control>> _tabControls 
                           = new Dictionary<TabPage, HashSet<Control>>();

    public OptionsForm()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterToValidationEvents();
    }

    private void RegisterToValidationEvents()
    {
        foreach (TabPage tab in this.OptionTabs.TabPages)
        {
            var tabControlList = new HashSet<Control>();
            _tabControls[tab] = tabControlList;
            foreach (Control control in tab.Controls)
            {
                var capturedControl = control; //this is necessary
                control.Validating += (sender, e) =>
                    tabControlList.Add(capturedControl);
                control.Validated += (sender, e) =>
                    tabControlList.Remove(capturedControl);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Ok_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ValidateChildren())
        {
            _settings.Save();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            var unvalidatedTabs = _tabControls.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Count != 0)
                                              .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
            TabPage firstUnvalidated = unvalidatedTabs.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstUnvalidated != null && 
                !unvalidatedTabs.Contains(OptionTabs.SelectedTab))
                    OptionTabs.SelectedTab = firstUnvalidated;
        }
    }
```